# How is $ used in higher order functions ?

Tags: haskell

This concerns an example encountered in [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application), namely this one :

```
ghci> map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
```

I'm trying to understand it but it makes no sense to me. Of course, the list of functions will be applied to the input (number 3) but I don't see how the `$` operator helps. I'm trying to trace the order of application of things (if there's a haskell IDE with a step through compiler please let me know) and can't understand how `$` being right associative allows flipping the function application, ie when I see `map` like this

```
map fun [1, 2 .. n]
```

I imagine the following happening to form the output list

```
fun 1
fun 2
.
.
fun n
```

but for the example at hand, how is this of meaning :

```
$3 4+
```

Comment: Your intuition is quite good, but it is more like `($ 3) (4 +)`. Then maybe `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` will help you to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how is this of meaning :
>
> ```
> $3 4+
> ```

That's not actually of meaning, indeed. But that's not what it simplifies to! It simplifies to

```
($3) (4+)
```

These things are *operator sections*.

```
($ 3) ≡ \x -> x $ 3
(4+)  ≡ \x -> 4 + x
(10*) ≡ \x -> 10*x
(^2)  ≡ \x -> x^2
```

so

```
($3) (4+) ≡ (\f -> f $ 3) (\y -> 4 + y)
          ≡ (\y -> 4 + y) $ 3 
          ≡ (\y -> 4 + y) 3
          ≡ 4 + 3
```

Perhaps it's easier to understand if you visualise the “holes”:

```
map (□ $ 3) [(4+□), (10*□), (□^2), sqrt □]
≡ [(4+□) $ 3, (10*□) $ 3, (□^2) $ 3, (sqrt □) $ 3]
≡ [(4+3), (10*3), (3^2), (sqrt 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator $ calls the function which is its left hand argument on the value which is its right hand argument. In the use of the example it "puts" the value 3 as additional argument of the sections in the list

Thus `($ 3) (4+)` is  `(4+3)`. Analogously `($ 2) (4/)` is  `(4/2)`

The use of sections is easier to grasp using normal arithmetic operations. For instance: `(/2) 4` is the same as `4/2` and thus 2